# R - Neural Networks - Iris Dataset

Tags: r, iris-dataset

I tried to use nnet on the iris dataset but I am not sure how to resolve the errors show below.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

```
library(nnet)
attach(iris)

library(caret)
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8,
                              list = FALSE,
                              times = 1)
irisTrain <- iris[ trainIndex,]
irisTest  <- iris[-trainIndex,]

irispred <- nnet(species ~ ., data=irisTrain, size=10)
predicted <- predict(irispred,irisTest,type="class")
```

**Error in model.frame.default(formula = species ~ ., data = irisTrain) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Length')**

Comment: This runs without an error for me, except for a typo in your formula (`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'species' not found`). `Species` should be upper case. Maybe that's the problem, as R may have found `species` in the global environment.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thanks. I don't know how I overlooked it.  I am asking another question on the results and the confusionMatrix.

Comment: See an example in this [blog](http://www.parallelr.com/r-deep-neural-network-from-scratch/)